# How can i return an Optional object if the list is empty

Tags: java, option-type

Need to filter through a list of items and check if item.discount() <= 0, in case none are found return Optional object type.

This is a code for adding values to list but I don't know how to get Optional object if the list is empty

```
Optional<List<Item>> discFit = Optional.of(items
           .stream()
           .filter(item -> item.getDiscount() <= 0)
           .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: you still have the optional, so you can still do "return discFit".

Comment: That is a very unusual requirement... A list that can either have items or be empty is _much_ easier to work with than an optional list that can either wrap a list with items in or an empty optional. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: We got a assignement in Java class we need to get this, maybe this code i wrote wrong

Comment: Maybe i need to use Optional.ofNullable() in discount

Comment: Are you REALLY sure you are supposed to return an `Optional<List<Item>>`? If you misunderstood the assignment, you're wasting your time by trying to do something completely useless.

Comment: And note: if the assignment is like that, then it is perfectly fair for you to go back to your instructor and ask for the purpose of this. Because the folks on stackoverflow told you: this isnt something you do in the real world.

Comment: It's that type of professor that just gives an assignement you need to do and that is it, if you dont upload it in time you get ZERO and we move on

Answer (score 1):

```
Optional<List<Item>> discFit = Optional.of(items
       .stream()
       .filter(item -> item.getDiscount() <= 0)
       .collect(Collectors.toList())).filter(l -> !l.isEmpty());
```

`Optional.filter` returns a value if the predicate matches or otherwise `Optional.empty`

But as mentioned there is rarely a good reason to wrap a list in an optional, because the list can be either empty or have values (usually returned lists aren't `null`) and wrapping the list in optional only makes it more complicated.

---

If you only need `Optional<Item>` (which makes more sense) there are different ways to get the result depending on what you actually want to do.

```
Optional<Item> discFit = items
       .stream()
       .filter(item -> item.getDiscount() <= 0)
       .findFirst();
```

This would return an `Optional` with the first `Item` that has a discount great than 0 or `Optional.empty()` if no `Ìtem` was found.

Comment: Can u change it up using Optional<Item> instead of Optional<List<Item>>

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you actually want to do.

Comment: FindFirst did the job, thank u